# Does Follow Me / Rage Powder redirect Heal Pulse / Floral Healing in 7th Gen Pokemon games?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

For example, in a Doubles battle, if an opposing Clefairy uses Follow Me, whilst your Comfey uses Floral Healing on its teammate. This also extends to Follow Me / Rage Powder (without Safety Googles), and Heal Pulse / Floral Healing / Pollen Puff used on an ally.

Strangely Google was very unhelpful with answering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Bulbapedia's page on Follow Me](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Follow_Me_(move)):

> Follow Me [...] makes the user the center of attention, forcing opposing Pokémon to use their moves on the user rather than the intended target (**even if it was a friendly target, unless it is a move that cannot target an opponent such as Acupressure or Helping Hand**) for the rest of the turn. If a move cannot target the center of attention, it will be used on its intended target.

Yes, moves such as Healing Pulse and Floral Healing will be redirected, as they can target the opponents.

Comment: Ah ok. So it's like Swagger in that regards e.g. Follow Me can be used to counter opposing Heal Pulse much like it counters side-Swagger.